# Check box issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have check box inside a foreach loop so that i want to checkbox checked.

```
<?php
    $heads = TCG\Voyager\Models\Head::all();
    $i=0;                                 
    foreach($heads as $heads){
        $headvalues=explode(',',$test->reporting_head);
        echo $headvalues[$i]; 
        echo '<br>';
        echo $heads->id;
?>
<input type="checkbox"  name="check_list[]" value="{{$heads->id}}_{{$heads->email}}" <?php echo (($headvalues[$i]==$heads->id)? 'checked' : ''); ?>><label>{{$heads->headname}}</label>
<?php 
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Here echo **$headvalues[$i]** are 1, 2 ,3 and echo **$heads->id** are 1,3,2.so i want to checked all this check boxes but now only one check box is checked.i think my logic has issue.I tried the following

```
<?php echo (($headvalues[$i]==$heads->id)? 'checked' : ''); ?>
```

Please help me

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz-i updated the question.please help me

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: actually ids 1 3 2 should checked but only first seems checked  others are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<?php echo (($headvalues[$i]==$heads->id)? 'checked' : ''); ?>
```

use

```
<?php echo (in_array($heads->id, $headvalues)? 'checked' : ''); ?>
```

Comment: -thnks dear...Your so sweet